# How to display posts for people you follow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails but after i followed michael hartl rails I was wondering how to view posts for people you follow ?

**User Model**

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
    has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy

    has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
    has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower


  def feed
    following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE  follower_id = :user_id"
    Post.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids})
                     OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)   end
    def follow(other)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other.id)   end   def unfollow(other)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other.id).destroy   end   def following?(other)
     following.include?(other)    end
```

**Relationship Controller**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate_user!

 def create
    user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end      

  end

  def destroy
    user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(user)
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end 


  end

    end
```

**RelationShip Model**

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

So I was hoping what is the code ? I tried `current_user.followed_id.posts` but didn't work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you already have the answer in your code.

The `User#feed` method will let you do it:

```
user = User.first
user.feed # => [<posts from the users that you follow>]
```

Comment: THANKS ALOT ...it works well in the console but whenever I call it in the view i get something like this #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x7b34920> It calls the object itself ... and I tried current_user.feed ,,, User.find(params[:id]).feed and I get the same

Comment: You will need to iterate through that object: `<% user.feed.each do |post| %>`...